# Make Span in sidebar appear on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to  have the menu items in my sidebar invisible and make them visible only when i hover over the sidebar

```css
.app{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #060606;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #9ca3af;
  display:block;
}

.sidebar span{
display:none;
}

/* is this part even a thing */
.sidebar:hover span{
visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
<dive class="sidebar"><span>123</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `visibility` property set to `visible` when the `.sidebar` element(s) are hovered by the user, unfortunately you chose to set the `display` property to `none`, and haven't updated that property-value, in order to allow it to be shown.

So, to correct the problem, use the same `property` in both places, and set the property-value in the default and `:hover` states.

To use `visibility`:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #060606;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #9ca3af;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.sidebar:hover span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar"><span>123</span></div>
</div>
```

Or you could use `display`:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #060606;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #9ca3af;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar span {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar:hover span {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar"><span>123</span></div>
</div>
```

There are of course other options, such as `opacity`, which allows for a transition between the hidden and visible states:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #060606;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #9ca3af;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

.sidebar:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar"><span>123</span></div>
</div>
```

And, of course, you can add additional properties such as `transform` to make the appearance more aesthetically pleasing (for a given value of 'aesthetically pleasing'), for example:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #060606;
  transition: all 1s;
  color: #9ca3af;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.4) rotateZ(-75deg);
  transition-property: opacity, transform;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.sidebar:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar"><span>123</span></div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).
- [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).
- [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).
- [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Answer (score 1):

```
You have to change .sidebar span to `display: none; visibility: hidden;` and when hover - `visibility: visible;` and `display: block;`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain your answer and use proper formatting to help people who may come across this answer. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer